# How to check caller is EP in X++

Tags: client, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I need to check in X++ if the caller is EP or Client so I can do some customization if the caller is EP in that code. Please let me know how is it possible

Note: I am using ListPageInteraction class for both EP and AX Client and I have to made some modification to same query (used for both) in case the caller is EP in ListPageInteraction class

Answer (score 0):

Check the NumberSeqNumCache.isEpClient method, it looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
///    Determines whether the request is from EP.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
///    true if EP is the caller; otherwise, false.
/// </returns>
static server boolean isEpClient()
{
     xSession session = new xsession();
     boolean isEP = false;
     sysClientSessions clientsessions;
     ;


    select ClientType from clientsessions where clientsessions.SessionId == session.sessionId();

    if (clientSessions.ClientType == SessionType::WebUser || clientsessions.clientType == SessionType::Worker)
    {
         isEp = true;
    }

    return isEp;
}
```

It checks if the current session is of type webuser or worker. If you ware using a client, the session would be of type SessionType::GUI. Mind though that other sessions may also register as type SessionType::Worker, for example batch tasks so this might not work everywhere.

Comment: Also check http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/69639.aspx, they say that checken for this is impossible (as far as they know, but if the above works then that will prove to be wrong).

Comment: I think the code snippet above mixes up clientTypes and sessionTypes. The sysClientSessions table has both clientType and sessionType. The base enums node under AOT, system documentation has the enumerated values  for both of them. That said, I don't know how to deduce whether it is EP or not.